# Error Registering Dll in windows 7

Tags: dll

Im getting the below error when trying to register dtspkg.dll in windows 7. The file is in the folder specifed. Any Idea?

[DLL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp3OW.png)

Comment: Right, C:\Program is not a DLL.  Put "double quotes" around the file name so the space in C:\Program Files does not confuzzle the tool.